# In EntityFramework, what is an efficient way to verify a code-first model matches a database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with EntityFramework (v6, but that shouldn't matter), and I have come across something I'm not sure how to handle. Basically, there were a bunch of databases with 'mostly' the same schema, used for various customers, storing their data. We are looking to use EF with them, in a code-first manner. Since the databases already exist, I will be using the "Reverse Engineer Code-First" functionality to create the necessary files and classes to describe our database.

My issue is, sometimes some of these existing databases might have minor inconsistencies in them, which may have slipped by undetected before, but which may prevent EF from working with them; case in point, when accessing one of these databases, a column was set as NON NULL, when the context was expecting it to be NULLable, and it threw a ConstraintException which prevented the context from working with it. My concern was that this exception didn't get thrown until I attempted to work with that specific table. Therefore I would like to be able to run some logic initially on customer login which first tries to verify that all of the tables in the context will be accessible to EntityFramework, and not have any of these errors; ie if there are going to be any problems I would like to be able to detect that initially with some kind database-wide integrity check, instead of later worrying about it when I access each specific table.

Has anyone run into this before? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have the database and you want that to be your 'master', why wouldn't you just do database first?

Comment: Well even if that were the case, the issue still remains, I'd have a model created from one database which may or may not match the database that gets loaded up. I want to be able to check that my model matches the database without having to wait until I access a specific entity from it.

Comment: This seems not to be a EF question. You just want to compare two databases. The one you create your model from and another one that gets loaded somehow.

Comment: @John if you went with database first then you would simply have to right click on your the EF designer and select 'update model from database'